# Добавить в controls тега video изменение качества видео

Tags: javascript, css, html5, видео

В теге video в controls, на сколько я понял, нету возможности добавить изменение качества видео посредствам редактирования параметров самого тега. Данный функционал легко дописать с помощью JS.

Как добавить выбор качества в стандартный controls(спозиционировать, сделать чтобы оставалось на месте в разных браузерах и при изменении размера окна)? Или все-же придется переписывать все управление видео чтобы добавить данную функцию? Интересно почему такая возможность не предусмотрена, или все-же предусмотрена, но я не разобрался просто?

Comment: Такой возможности в обычном теге `video` не предусмотрено. По этому придётся писать "переключатель".

Comment: @De.Minov Написать не сложно - проблема с тем как его прикрепить на controls, можно ли например подвинуть другие элементы(те, которые предусмотрены) с помощью css, или, по крайней мере просто спозиционировать переключатель этот относительно controls? Как? Или писать полностью все элементы управления самому и не прописывать controls единственный путь?

Comment: Вообще никак не отредактировать controls, может пару браузеров и могут, но не все и скорее всего через те ещё костыли. Лучше написать свой controls, а еще лучше заюзать готовую либу.